# How to set higher timeout in a class

Tags: elasticsearch

This works if the data is not very big. (for e.g. upto 5 MB)

```
import eland as ed
df = ed.DataFrame('localhost:9200', 'kibana_sample_data_flights')
df.to_csv('abc.csv')
```

But getting timeout error after 10 seconds if the data is large.

```
ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx', port=xxx): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
```

Is there anyway to modify default timeout in that class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287261/connection-timeout-with-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `eland` is based on, `elasticsearch`, allows you to [set the Timeout parameter](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/api.html) yourself. And the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/eland/) for `eland` elaborates on how to use `eland` and `elasticsearch` libraries together to make your requests.

You could make the request using `elasticsearch` and [get a `DataFrame` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186148/creating-dataframe-from-elasticsearch-results#41092377), which you then `to_csv` without needing to change your code very much at all.

I hope my response was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct connection object that I need to include timeout.

```
import eland as ed
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{"host": "localhost", "port": 9200, "timeout": 120}])
df = ed.DataFrame(es, es_index_pattern="kibana_sample_data_flights")
```